# filter pandas dataframe columns with null data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 200+ columns. I'm trying to inspect all the columns with null data. How can I filter/display the columns which have null data? df.isnull().sum() lists count of all columns, but I want to see only columns with non-zero null data count as the number of columns is high.

Comment: can we see an example dataframe and expected output?

Comment: @ user2305776 , pls see the detailed answer below don't forget to accept if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the counts, just filter on the entries greater than zero:

```
null_counts = df.isnull().sum()
null_counts[null_counts > 0]
```

Comment: Simple and nice! Thx

Answer (score 5):

Newer Pandas versions have new methods [DataFrame.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)  and  [DataFrame.notna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)

**1) Using `DataFrame.isna()` method !**

```
>>> df
    A     B     C     D  E      F
0   0   1.0   2.0     3  4    one
1   3   5.0   NaN   NaT  5    two
2   8   NaN  10.0  None  6  three
3  11  12.0  13.0   NaT  7   four
```

To get Just the List of Columns which are null values:

```
>>> df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()
['B', 'C', 'D']
```

To list down all the columns which are having nan values.

```
>>> df.loc[:, df.isna().any()]
      B     C     D
0   1.0   2.0     3
1   5.0   NaN   NaT
2   NaN  10.0  None
3  12.0  13.0   NaT
```

**2) Using `DataFrame.isnull()` method !**

To get Just the List of Columns which are null values, returns type is boolean.

```
>>> df.isnull().any()
A    False
B     True
C     True
D     True
E    False
F    False
dtype: bool
```

To get Just the List of Columns which are null having values:

```
>>> df.columns[df.isnull().any()].tolist()
['B', 'C', 'D']
```

To select a subset - all columns containing at least one `NaN` value:

```
>>> df.loc[:, df.isnull().any()]
      B     C     D
0   1.0   2.0     3
1   5.0   NaN   NaT
2   NaN  10.0  None
3  12.0  13.0   NaT
```

If you want to count the missing values in each column:

```
>>> df.isnull().sum()
A    0
B    1
C    1
D    3
E    0
F    0
dtype: int64
```

OR

```
>>> df.isnull().sum(axis=0)  # axis=0 , across the columns
A    0
B    1
C    1
D    3
E    0
F    0

# >>> df.isnull().sum(axis=1)  # across the rows
```

**Finally, to get the total number of NaN & non NaN values in the DataFrame:**

Nan value counts

```
>>> df.isnull().sum().sum()
```

Non NaN  value count

```
>>> df.notnull().sum().sum()
```

Comment: Thx for showing the various options available. Since I wanted to see "only those columns with null values and their count", I selected the other answer. Thx for your response.

Comment: @user2305776, no problem , by the way i edited my post in case you are looking for total nul counts.